# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() doesn't work on physical device

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I have a problem with showing location on physical device when locationManager is set to `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()`.

Everything works in Simulator but when I make it run on my iPhone there is no coordinates returned, and if I change it to `startUpdatingLocation()` it works on my physical device.

Any idea what could be wrong?

My code:

```
  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        startReceivingSingificantLocationChanges()
    }

    func startReceivingSingificantLocationChanges() {

        if !CLLocationManager.significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable() {
            //the service is not available
            print("Service is not available")
            return
        }

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first{
            print(location.coordinate)
            coordinatesLbl.text = "LAT:\(location.coordinate.latitude) LONG:\(location.coordinate.longitude)"
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.denied{
            showLocationDisabledPopUp()
            print("didChangeAuthorization")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati) on `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` states:

> Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters or more from its previous notification. It should not expect notifications more frequently than once every five minutes. If the device is able to retrieve data from the network, the location manager is much more likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner.

So you shouldn't expect them very often when using this method.

`startUpdatingLocation` updates much more often, which is why this works.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but isn't it suppose to give you current location and then update it after 500-1km? Now it's returning no coordinates at all.

Comment: the docs say `The first event to be delivered is usually the most recently cached location event (if any)` so you might not get the first one

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and had the same issue. I ended up setting the location `desiredAccuracy` to `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer`. This had the desired effect of giving me significant location changes. Another way to do this is to use `startUpdatingLocation` and once you have the current location, change the location manager to `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`.